# In QGIS I want to display a piechart per region not per country

Tags: charts, qgis

Mac OS X 10.9
QGIS 2.4

I have a shapefile for the world.
For each country it has the UN designated subregion code.
I have some external data that maps to that subregion code.
I want to show that as a piechart superimposed on the map.

I have added as vector layer, joined on the subregion attribute.
Then I do: Properties > Diagram > Display Pie Chart

Problem is that because the Data links to each country in the subregion I get N piecharts per region - because the shapefile is country level but the external data is region level (I have country level but just much too messy to display 200 pie charts!)

e.g
There are 10 countries with subregion code for West Africa so when I join the external data and then display it I get the same all-West-Africa Pie chart displayed 10 times over each individual country.

I just want to display 1 pie chart for West Africa, 1 for East Africa etc., etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use your dataset and use dissolve polygons on the UN regions
2. join your data
3. draw pie charts
4. add your original country shapefile
5. make the features in the dissolved polygon transparent